# collectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath issue

Tags: ios6, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have an interesting issue with `collectionView`, specifically, `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`.

My app has one particular view with a background image, which is accessed via an SQL. Within that view is a popover, with a collectionView, to change the parent view's background, and access other "sets" available for purchase.

My issue is with the changing of the background. All items display correctly in the collection view and the parent's background will change as it should. The problem is that the item selected is not the one that displays, even though via `NSLog`, I can see that the correct image is being selected and passed back to the parent. There is a corresponding `NSLog` in the parent, which shows the same image id as the popover's `NSLog`.

The first item in the `collectionView`, when tapped, will change the background of the parent to  white, as if there was no image available. Tapping the second cell will display the first cell's image. Tapping the third cell will display the second cell's image... and so on. There are 15 images available to select from.

This is the `didSelect` method:

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([_currentView isEqualToString:@"New_Journal"])
    {
        MyAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MyAppDelegate *)[UIApplication.sharedApplication delegate];
        // to get the variable back to the parent
        appDelegate.loadBackgroundID = indexPath.row; 
        // interact with the SQL via _settingsDao
        [_settingsDao updateJournalBackgroundId:_journalId withBackgroundId:appDelegate.loadBackgroundID];
        NSLog(@"Selected background: %d", indexPath.row);
        // notification to let EntryView know the background has changed
        [NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter postNotificationName:@"aBackgroundChanged" object:self];
    }
}
```

Edit to show SQL interaction method:

```
-(void)updateJournalBackgroundId:(int)journalID withBackgroundId:(int)newBackgroundId
{
    NSString *query = @"UPDATE BgIconBorderSettings SET background_id = ? WHERE journal_id = ?";
    FMDatabase *db = [dbUtils sharedDB];
    [db executeUpdate:query,[NSNumber numberWithInt:newBackgroundId],[NSNumber numberWithInt:journalID]];
    if([db hadError])
    {
        NSLog(@"Error %d: %@",[db lastErrorCode],[db lastErrorMessage]);    
    }       
}
```

Anyone have any ideas on how to get the correct image of the tapped cell to display? Thanks for any assistance in solving this issue.

As jhilgert pointed out... it was the SQL database. It started at 1 and not 0. Changed the ids and it works as expected.

Comment: There's got to be a math problem with the object it's fetching maybe. Can you post the code you use to interact with SQL ?

Comment: just a hunch, but what does the NSlog give you for newBackgroundId, and journalID? Does it match indexPath.section, and indexPath.row?

Comment: They do match... indexPath.row, newBackgroundId. The logs match for each tap. There is only one section. The displayed EntryView journalId  matches the database journalID. If they didn't match, I could understand the difference in the background image.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is if your database (columns or tables, or however you're storing them in SQL) is not starting out at 0 like indexPath does?

Comment: Do you get any crashes when selecting the last item in the collection view?

Comment: No, there are no crashes, even if cycle through every available background. As for the storing method... the app has been live on the store since 2010 and it used a custom grid view that worked just fine. The view was a little glitchy in paging, starting with iOS5, so I decided to swap it out. It was only when I changed the view to one that contained a collectionView that this anomaly appeared.

Comment: jhilgert00... thanks for the tip. I had to change directions last year and stayed with the "old way", which was a custom grid. This year, I have swapped out and ran into the same issue. And, yes, the SQL was starting at 1 instead of 0. Changed that... done, problem solved. Thanks for your help.